# How to use Cunit with Mingw64 on Windows?

Tags: mount, configure, mingw64

I'm trying to run some test on Windows, using Mingw64. I got Mingw64 with gcc 4.7 from rubenvb builds on sourceforge, and I additionally downloaded some Unix utilities from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/ because I needed `sed`, but, it's not clear how this should be used. I only unzipped it in MinGW64 directory and copied the .exe files from UnxUtils to MinGW64\bin when I needed them, and it works.

Then, I have a CUnit folder containing some .h files (I got it from the previous Linux environment and just copy/paste it on Windows) and put it in MinGW64\lib\gcc...\include. I have a test file that is looking for CUnit.h, and it can find it (because I put the folder here, it wasn't able to find it before that). However, when I try to compile using the  `-lcunit` option, I got this error: `ld.exe: cannot find -lcunit`

I've tried to copy the CUnit folder in every `\include`directory in MinGW64, but it wasn't better. I thought that maybe copying the folder wasn't enough and I had to properly reinstall lcunit. So I downloaded the latest version here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cunit/files/ and tried to follow some "howTo" to install it, but I got 2 problems:

1) It says I should use `mount` to see where my MinGW64 is 'mounted'. I'm not sure what that means, and I don't even have the `mount` command. But the example show that it should give a result like `C:\MinGW64    /mingw`, which looks a lot like fstab file from MinGW. However, my MinGW64 doesn't have such a file.

2) if I use the "default" options, it said that I should go into the CUnit (unzipped) folder and type `./configure --host=x86_64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw`, but... I don't have the `configure` command either.

And I'm stuck here, I don't know how to add the configure or mount command to my MinGW64 (since it's a complete Toolchain, unlike MinGW where you can add things to the basic install), and I'm not even sure that installing cunit will solve my problem. So any idea is welcome :)

(Please note that I only have MinGW64, not MSYS or Cygwin, and I'd prefer avoid installing those)

Answer (score 0):

I can half answer half of your question. `configure` is not a command, it is just a conventional name for any script that detects what kind of system you are running, and prepares the project for installation on that system. In fact, in this case there is a file called `configure.in`, which usually means you need to run `autoconf` (part of a suite called autotools) in order to generate the `configure` script from that file. I'm afraid this is where my knowledge ends, but I thought I'd answer in the hope that it helps you in the right direction.

Comment: that does help me in my research for a solution. It seems that I need autotools, and this is not available in MinGW; so i'll need to get either MSYS or Cygwin to make it works. Thanks.